# Accordion open/close all content button and more

Tags: javascript, html, button, toggle, accordion

I have a responsive accordion function inside a website and i want to (open) and (close) all content with one button that also change his content name to (open) when all content is closed and (closed) when all content is open.

Also now the content that already was opened closes again when using the (open) button and the plus and minus icons don't react the right way showing the (minus icon) when the content is closed and visa versa.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/foroloca/w3srayj6/14/)

Can someone help me with this?

```
// Accordion //

$('.header').click(function(){
    $('.content',$(this).parent()).slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
})

$('.toggle-btn').click(function(){
    $('.content').slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go:
http://jsfiddle.net/w3srayj6/21/

```
// Accordion //

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.header').click(function(){
        $('.content',$(this).parent()).slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
         $('.toggle-btn').addClass('active').trigger("change"); 
    })

});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle-btn').change(function(){
        var headers = $('.header');
        var state = 'open';
        $.each(headers,function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('active'))
                state = 'close';
        });
        if(state == 'open')
            $(this).addClass('active')
        $(this).text(state);
    });
    $('.toggle-btn').click(function(){
        var current = $(this);
        current.toggleClass('active');
        current.trigger("change");
        var contents = $('.content');
        $.each(contents, function(){
            if(!current.hasClass('active'))
                $(this).slideUp();
            else
                $(this).slideDown();
        });
        var headers = $('.header');
        $.each(headers, function(){
            if(current.hasClass('active'))
                $(this).addClass('active');
            else
                $(this).removeClass('active');
        });      
       current.trigger("change");
    })

});

// Read more //

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 20) {
        $('.read-more').slideDown(200);
    } else {
        console.log('there');
        $('.read-more').slideUp(200);
    }
});
```

Sometimes working with toggles may be a bit tricky and confusing.

In this case I used "hasClass" in order to determine if items are already open or not.
Since we have only "opened" and "closed" states, we can say that as long that "open" is not "Active" (has class active on it), we should add the "active" class flag to all headers and contents. same in the opposite situation.
this makes sure that already toggled items are not re-toggled.

Comment: thanks mate! Great! Where can i put the change open to close state in this script?

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand your question

Comment: Sorry it's becoming confusing because there a lot of different states, but even if there is one content opened the button change its name to close and function like that and if all or one are closed or opened separately by hand the button changes name to open orclose. Sorry for my English hope you understand. Thanks for helping! [New fiddle with your code and button state] (http://jsfiddle.net/foroloca/w3srayj6/16/)

Comment: For that I used another event handler "change" which is called whenever a header is set as "active" or button was pressed: http://jsfiddle.net/w3srayj6/18/   (please rate if my answers were helpful :) )

Comment: Thanks mate! Only have one issue left i think, when clicking on open all open of course, but when closing one or two etc by hand the close function works as open. How do i rate your answers, because your are very helpful! Can't see where?

Comment: Should be fixed here: http://jsfiddle.net/w3srayj6/19/ . it happend because we removed the 'active' class from the button, which made it ignore opened items. and for rating : please mark the question with "V" and press the "up" arrow :)

Comment: Mate you're the best! Amazing script writing skills! But the last script does something weird it makes the 'open-close-button' disappear floats to the top and after that a extra horizontal scrollbar appears also during that the slide down animation shifts a bit. Sorry for bugging you with this again, but there is something in the script that wasn't before that causes that i think. You can't see it happening in fiddle only running for real. Hope you can help again ;-)

Comment: I think i have it i removed this: $(this).toggleClass(state) and i think it works correctly now ;-) Don't know why this causes the button to go on top of the website, but it did. ;-)

Comment: Sorry i'm annoying one thing left i think: when opening one or more content sections by hand and close them the same way the 'open-button' doesn't react on first click only after the second onclick. Do you know what that is?

Comment: You're the best! Thank so much! Shame there is only one V to mark for you ;-) Again thanks!

Comment: No problem :) u can always press the up button next to my answers :)

Answer (score 0):

If you check for the class `active` after the toggle occurs, you can then change the text of the button depending on if the toggled class is active or not.

**[See this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mvu2zkhs/)** (edited to change the icons also)

Comment: Thanks Mark great help! but there is still a issue with the fact that if someone already opened a section it closes when they open all content and visa versa when closing.

Comment: Also when someone closes every content by hand and not by the main close button the name of the button and functions stays the same also visa versa when someone opened all content by hand.

Comment: @foroloca you would just loop through the elements and check if they have the class `active` at the same time the button has the class `active`. If so, skip it. If it doesn't, then add the class (and vice-versa)

Comment: @foroloca that can happen too. It will take a bit of tweaking to get fixed. Best I can do right now is point you in the right direction as I don't have a ton of free time at this time of the day

Comment: Ok Mark understand appreciate your help. Hope that i get it working ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To change your minus/plus icone with your button, you must select specific .header class with parent() and child() jQuery method like this :

```
$('.toggle-btn').click(function(){
    $('.content').each( function() { 
    $(this).slideToggle();
    $(this).parent().find('.header').toggleClass('active');
     });
});
```

Comment: thank you thibault! this code looks cleaner, but how would you write the code for changing name on button and solve the problem when a content is already opened closes again when clicking open.